# dynamic string localization in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, string, localization

I have a C#/WPF application and I am attempting to add multi-language support. From my looking around I've found that using resource files of string values for each language is how I should go about doing this. Then update the CultureInfo. This seems to work fine if the culture info is set at or before the creation of the window, but I want the ability to dynamically change the culture. How can I do this? I've tried playing around with binding and dynamicResource, but couldn't figure out how to get either one to work. I guess I should add that I'm pretty much a beginner with the WPF stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this Codeplex project](http://codeplex.com/wpflocalizeextension). It provides a dynamic localization system that blends well with WPF's binding system.

Comment: hard to trust a language package that misspells 'really' at the top of the page.

Comment: Granted, the guy should have someone proof-read his page, it's full of spelling/grammatical mistakes...
But don't be too harsh on the guy, nobody said he is a native English speaker.

Comment: This package is awesome. The best way to get away with WPF localization if you find what MSDN offer is way too complicated.